# Expression of the unit tangent to a curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vectors, curves

I am trying to prove the following expression:

By expanding the RHS of the expression, show that
$$
\frac{d\hat{T}}{dt}=\frac{r'\times(r''\times r')}{{\Vert r\Vert}^3}
$$

where $\hat T$ is the unit tangent vector to a curve, i.e. $\hat T=\frac{r'}{\Vert r'\Vert}$

I used the vector triple product to find the numerator which gives me $r''(r'\cdot r')-r'(r'\cdot r'')$
I know that $r'\cdot r'={\Vert r'\Vert}^2$, but I do not know how to simplify the second bracket.

Does anyone have any suggestions or could push me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that you have a typo in the denominator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{d\hat T\over dt}=
{d\over dt}{r'\over\sqrt{r'\cdot r'}}={r''\over\sqrt{r'\cdot r'}}
-{r'\over2}{2r'\cdot r''\over(r'\cdot r')^{3/2}}=
{r''(r'\cdot r')-r'(r'\cdot r'')\over(r'\cdot r')^{3/2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now